# Thread safe on Inheritance of spring boot controller

Tags: spring-boot, inheritance, thread-safety

I am writing an API using Spring Boot, and I have a abstract controller to hold the shared logic among several controllers. Now I want to add a `warning` field:

```
public abstract class BaseController<T> {
   public List<String> warnings;

    @RequestMapping(method = POST)
    public Response create(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {
      warnings = new ArrayList<>();
      if (something bad from T) {
        warning.add("bad thing happens");
      }
      return createRespone(warnings);
}
```

(`createReponse` is uesd to create custom reponse)

And I have several different controller inherited from it

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/{area}/blah")
public class BlahController extends BaseController<Blah> {
}
```

For the `warning` field, will it be shared several different children controller, or will only one instance alive? If `controller A` and `controller B` are both inherited from `BaseController` and tried to modify warning, is it thread safe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning field is not shared. Your code is equivalent to:

```
BaseController<blah> blahController = new BlahController();
BaseController<noh> nohController = new NohController();
```

Having state in a controller is against the REST concepts.